# Drawbacks of using Activity as singleton

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, singleton

I have one activity, with many fragments on it. 
Since I sometimes need the activity (for example to get getFragmentManager, etc.), I call the activty's singleton instance from fragment.
It means :
in my activity there's a **static** variable called instance.
However, sometimes I get crashes in fragments because MyActivity.getInstance() is null.

```
 1. How is it possible? Could it be because the activity is singleton?
 2. the activity-as-singleton - could it lead to certain problems(like **memory leak** ?, etc..)
 3. Can I count on getActivity always? I think sometimes that too returned null.
```

Comment: You no need to maintain instance in activity because fragments are placed inside the activity so you can get activity instance just by calling getActivity() in fragments.

Comment: you should not need to make static variable in activity. getActivity() method gives you current activity from fragment

Comment: but I think getActivity can too sometimes return null, no ?

Answer (score 1):

haven't come across such situation but rather than accessing resources like `getFragmentManager()` in fragment for fragment transaction, try Interface pattern and give callback to your activity and let activity handle all of this.